# Get Entity Object from string using reflection

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entityobject

I am able to obtain an object set with this code:

```
string tableName = "States";
var test = db.GetType().GetProperty(tableName).GetValue(db, null);

//this returns {System.Data.Objects.ObjectSet<FmlaModel.State>}
```

However, I would like to first find the **EntityObject** `FmlaModel.State`, so that I can explicitly name my variable type (like `ObjectSet<EntityObject>` instead of `var`), and so that I can use this to tell my form (TableEditor, see below) what type of EntityObject we are using.

Is there a way I can do this using reflection?  I have searched quite a bit, but have not found anything that works yet...

**EDIT:**
My goal is to be able to have a db table containing the names of entity objects we will be able to edit.  The names will be loaded into a combobox, and when one is selected, I will create an instance of my "Table Editor" form with something like

```
TableEditor<myEntityObject> tableEditor 
     = new TableEditor<myEntityObject>(myEntitySet<myEntityObject>);
```

My "Table Editor" class looks like this:

```
public partial class TableEditor<TEntity> : Form
    where TEntity : EntityObject
{
    public TableEditor(ObjectSet<TEntity> something)
    {
    ...
```

Comment: Can you shed more light on what this "so that I can explicitly name my variable (and be able to use FmlaModel.State in other contexts)" means and in general what you are up to?

Comment: @Pawel My apologies, please see my updated question... hopefully that will clear it up a little...

Comment: This seems like an XY problem to me. You want to do X, you think Y is the way to do it so you ask about Y. Why would you want to do this? What is the MAIN problem that needs to be solved?

Comment: @RyanBennett I appreciate your comment, but I tried to clear that up with my edit... I'm not sure what else to tell you... =P  Basically, I'm trying to create a generic "Table Editor" class that I can pass any of the Entities in my EF model to, so that a user can edit the table.  But I can't figure out how to grab an EntityObject with a string using reflection (or any other method).

Comment: You could try something along these lines http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12455389/entity-framework-get-entity-by-name