# How to have a unique C# code with different Entities EF having the same columns

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Good morning everybody,

I am doing a **AngularJS** project using **ASP.NET-MVC**, **C#**, **EF** and an **SQL Express** DB.

I have an **HTML** page calling some AngularJS functions calling some functions on `MyController.cs`.

In `MyController.cs` I have quite a lot functions using **EF**.

In my DB, I have hundred of tables with the same columns.

And I want to have the same HTML page for each table, so executing the same functions with different names

For example when I go to the link `http://..../Index/TABLE1`, `MyController.cs` would look like :

```
public ActionResult getCaptions()
{
    JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    serializer.MaxJsonLength = 500000000;
    var data =
        _db
        .TABLE1
        .OrderBy(i => i.CodeId)
        .ToArray();
    return Content(serializer.Serialize(data).ToString(), "application/json");
}
```

and when I go to the link `http://..../Index/TABLE2`, `MyController.cs` would look like :

```
public ActionResult getCaptions()
{
    JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    serializer.MaxJsonLength = 500000000;
    var data =
        _db
        .TABLE2
        .OrderBy(i => i.CodeId)
        .ToArray();
    return Content(serializer.Serialize(data).ToString(), "application/json");
}
```

I have thought about a solution like this :

> Declare a global variable on the controller `tableName`
>
> Modify the Index ActionResult

```
public ActionResult Index(string id)
{
    tableName = id;
    return View();
}
```

> Now I am stuck ...

Any help is needed, thanks.

**EDIT : If you downvote, can you at least explain why ? Thanks**

Comment: `db.Set<TableType>()`...

Comment: Didn't get your comment @CodeCaster

Comment: Instead of `_db.TABLE1`, `_db.TABLE2` you can make it a generic method `GetCaptions<T>()` and use `_db.Set<T>` to get the DbSet for the entity `T`.

Comment: I think you didn't get my question... I've tried what you did here but I still don't understand... The `T` is not defined. How can I set the `T` from a `URL string` ? @CodeCaster

Comment: @aBennouna: I am not sure whether Entity Framework is a good fit for your case. Entity Framework is strong if you want to model business objects (entities) and map them to tables. You have a lot of equally-shaped tables. Why is that? What do they represent? Why is data of the same shape stored in (hunderds of) different tables? Do you write to or only read from those? Maybe it is simpler to use plan SQL statements with ADO.NET to read the tables out?

Comment: Thats what I've done @chiccodoro.. Cheers

Comment: @eBennouna - wow that was quick. What do you mean by "that's what I've done"? I just recommended preferring ADO.NET over Entity Framework. Your example shows entity framework code and is tagged entity-framework...

Comment: @chiccodoro I've changed all my functions to plain SQL code, it's more easier. I don't have access to the tables, I can only read, write on the tables but I can't modify them. So I put the name of the table as a variable and do somthing like `"SELECT * FROM '" + tableName + "'"`

Comment: @aBennouna - does it mean your question is obsolete? Then you may want to retract (delete or close) it?

Answer (score 1):

I see you @aBennouna may have already given up on this question, but I took an interest in the question and decided it needed a solution. It may not be 100% what you asked for since here you can't take in a table name as a string parameter.

First if all the tables have same columns, you can inherit them from a same base:

```
public class TableBase
{
    [Key]
    public int CodeId { get; set; }
    public int Prop1 { get; set; }
    public int Prop2 { get; set; }
    public int Prop3 { get; set; }
}
```

Using this base we can define our tables:

```
public class Table1 : TableBase
{
}

public class Table2 : TableBase
{
}

// etc...
```

This enables us to write a generic **GetCaptions** method like @CodeCaster suggested (thanks for the nudge in right direction):

```
public ActionResult GetCaptions<T>() where T : TableBase
    {
        var set = db.Set<T>();

        // get all objects to array
        var list = set.OrderBy(i => i.CodeId).ToList();
        // serialize and return result

        // OR get single object and a value
        var item = set.FirstOrDefault();
        var propertyValue = item.Prop1;
    }
```

**Usage:**

```
GetCaptions<Table1>();
GetCaptions<Table2>();
```