# Entity Framework - How to load data by name of Entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Can i load entity data by name as:

```
using (var db = new DatabaseEntities())
            {
                db["NameOfEntity"].ToList();
            }
```

Thanks

Comment: So you know the name only at runtime?

Comment: There is an answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12455389/entity-framework-get-entity-by-name

Comment: @TimSchmelter: I want build a class that load data dynamic for an entity. Input is name of entity. Do you have any solution? Thank

Answer (score 0):

You can get them by Type

```
public class DatabaseEntities : DbContext
{

    public object GetList(string entityName)
    {
        return GetList(Type.GetType(entityName));
    }

    private List<TEntity> GetList<TEntity>(TEntity type) where TEntity : class
    {
        return Set<TEntity>().ToList();
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, if i use say "Employee" for type it'll get type object for Employee and use this type object as generic parameter. Then it'll execute line `Set<Type>().ToList();` and it'll obviously throw

Comment: Thank @Arvin, it's worked